# What happened to Cross in Assassin's Creed 3 when he was attacking Desmond?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

So Cross was attacking Desmond when he was in Abstergo Industries and he was about to shoot Desmond when he suddenly freaked out and held his head in pain! What exactly happened to him?

Comment: I strongly recommend you read the tie-in comics if you want to know more about Daniel Cross.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Daniel Cross](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Daniel_Cross) was suffering from the [Bleeding Effect](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Bleeding_Effect) when he confronted Desmond Miles. This was why he was holding his head and speaking in Russian. Bleeding effect is a disorder wherein the genetic memories of one's ancestor begins to blend in with the person's own memories.

Comment: Desmond also is suffering from the Bleeding Effect, although he has learned to control it, in part thanks to the events of the third AC II game.

Answer (score 0):

Remember in Revelations what they said would happen to Desmond if he did not finish Eizo's story? It's the same thing, but not doing anything to stop it.